# Layout trap or GHCi bug?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I was bitten by a strange layout "feature" of GHCi:

```
$ cat > problem.hs


l = [6
, 5]

t = do { putStrLn "line1"
; putStrLn "line2" }
```

When loading this into GHCi, I get an error `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)` on the line with the comma, but not on the line with the semicolon. I was under the impression that both bracketed `[…]` and braced `{…}` structures suspend layout, so this came as a surprise to me. Can somebody tell if this is behaviour in line with the Haskell spec, or just a GHC(i) bug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is in accordance with the Haskell spec. Layout doesn't care about parens or square brackets at all.

Comment: My understanding is that `{...}` suspends layout, but nothing else does. In particular, neither `(...)` nor `[...]` has any effect on layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, curly braces suspend layout, but no other lexical constructs do. The way to think of this is that the *only purpose* of curly braces in that particular lexical position is to suspend layout. There are no constructs that do other things *and also* affect layout.

(Of course curly braces used in other lexical positions have a different meaning entirely, related to record syntax).

Comment: "the only purpose of curly brackets is to suspend layout". Is there another way to update a record, like `let newRec = oldRec { value = newValue }`?

Comment: @Mephy you're right -- in another lexical position they serve a different purpose. I edited my answer accordingly.